# Can duplicate datastore key_name's be used in different entity kinds, and get_or_insert()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, primary-key

I have two model kinds, `CourtDays` and Days:

```
class CourtDays(db.Model):    #parent is Courts
    court = db.ReferenceProperty(Courts)
    reserveMaxTimeBefore = db.ListProperty(int)   
    reserveMinTimeBefore = db.ListProperty(int)
    day = db.StringProperty()

class Days (db.Model):
    court = db.ReferenceProperty(Courts)
    startTime = db.ListProperty(int)
    endTime = db.ListProperty(int)
    startTimeLunch = db.ListProperty(int)
    endTimeLunch = db.ListProperty(int)
    name = db.StringProperty()
```

Can I remove the "day" in `CourtDays` and the "name" in `Days` and instead use `key_name="day"` and `key_name="name"` for put()ing the two kinds even though "day" and "name" are the seven days of the week? Notice that both `CourtDays` and `Days` have the same ReferenceProperty *(and will have the same parent, too)*. Also, notice that other `CourtDays` and Days will have the same days involved, but for other Courts which are parented and referenced by other CourtLocations.

Also, can the method `get_or_insert()` be used to make sure that the `CourtDays` or `Days` entity for, say "Monday", can be revised but kept unique? I ask because the [datastore docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert) say "The get and subsequent (possible) put operations are wrapped in a transaction to ensure atomicity. Ths means that `get_or_insert()` **will never overwrite an existing entity**, ..." . Despite that phrase and because of it, does this mean that a "Model.get_or_insert (key_name, **kwds)" can be followed by a `put()` and overwrite the particular instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two entities can have the same key_name if they have different kinds, namespaces or parents. If two keys has same kinds, ids, parents and app_id they both points to the same entity.

I believe that phrase **will never overwrite an existing entity** means that `get_or_insert` will never put entity to datastore if there is an entity with such a key (property values does not metter). And yes, followed `put()` will overwrite that instance.